# How to manage variables/secrets for mulitple hosts only once with Ansible?se

Tags: variables, ansible, shared, secret-key

I'm currently looking into ways on what the best way to manage shared secrets between multiple hosts is. I only want to specify those secrets in a central place only once, and not in multiple files, etc.

More specifically, I have a role that is assigned to many hosts. I'm using variables with default values and specific overrides to customize the involved configuration file(s) - pretty much straight out of the Ansible documentation.

For one particular aspect, though, I need a shared secret between pairs of hosts, e.g. `hostA` will share a secret with `hostB`, but `hostA` shares a different secret with `hostC`.

Simplifying the problem and boiling it down to code, it looks something like this:

### Task in playbook, which will be run on all hosts:

```
- name: manage secrets
  template: src=secrets.j2 dest=/etc/secrets owner=root group=root mode=0600
```

### Template

```
{% for secret in abc.secrets %}
secret {{ secret }}
{% endfor %}
```

### Variables

```
abc:
  someAttribute: 123
  secrets:
    - 123
    - 234
```

I'm now trying to only have secrets on each hosts, that it actually needs instead of having all secrets on all hosts (as in the example above).

My idea is something like this:

#### Having a global structure with secrets along with a list of host that it affects, e.g.

```
secrets:
  - secret: 123
    hosts:
      - hostA
      - hostB
  - secret: 234
    hosts:
      - hostA
      - hostC
```

#### Setting the variables for specific hosts with `set_fact`

This is what is currently not working for me. Looking for ways on how to implement this and/or even for better approaches all together.

Comment: A little confused...just wanted to understand you want to create a var file using jinja2 template or a var file is there you just need to map the secret of the vars with the hosts as defined in the var ?

Comment: Well, in the end I don't mind (for now). I just want to end up with configuration file(s) with shared secrets between pairs of hosts. My idea was to have a global variable were all secrets/variables are defined - along with a list of hosts that are affected by this variable / secret. Then I need some Ansible magic to get it on the appropriate host(s).

Answer (score 2):

As `ansible` is host centric I would also go with a host centric data structure. When you define something like this, then you also have all the secrets defined only once and in one central place.

```
secrets:
  secretAB: '123'
  secretAC: '234'
  secretBC: '345'

myhosts:
  - host: 'hostA'
    secrets:
      - '{{ secrets.secretAB }}'
      - '{{ secrets.secretAC }}'
  - host: 'hostB'
    secrets:
      - '{{ secrets.secretAB }}'
      - '{{ secrets.secretBC }}'
  - host: 'hostC'
    secrets:
      - '{{ secrets.secretAC }}'
      - '{{ secrets.secretBC }}'
```